# View de duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, table, view, id

Tenho duas tabelas, TABLE_1 e TABLE_2 e quero criar uma view com alguns campos de ambas onde o id_event (existente em ambas) seja igual.

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    id INT,
    id_event INT,
    col1_t1 varchar(255),
    ...);

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
    id INT,
    id_event INT,
    col1_t2 varchar(255),
    col2_t2 varchar(255),
    ...);
```

O objectivo é ter a view com os campos TABLE1.id, TABLE2.id, TABLE2.col1_t2 e TABLE2.col2_t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) comparando o `id_event` nas duas tabelas:

```
SELECT T1.id, T2.id, T2.col1_t2, T2.col2_t2 
FROM table_1 AS T1
INNER JOIN table_2 AS T2
WHERE T1.id_event = T2.id_event
```

Abraços.